# Related models with conditions in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.3

If I have two tables, in a has-and-belongs-to-many relationships (e.g. members and events), and a join table (e.g. MemberEvents), how do I specify that Events exist in a conditional relationship to members - that is, I want to select some group of members, based on some critieria of events? I need to do it using my model code, not my controller code - fat models, thin controllers, after all.

The cakephp manual is not very clear on this point and its exacerbated by the fact that the following code (which does what I want):

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Member' => array(
        'className' => 'Member',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    ),
    'ConfirmedMembers'=> array(
        'className' => 'Member',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => array('EventsMember.is_confirmed'=>1)
    ),
    'UnconfirmedMembers'=> array(
        'className' => 'Member',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => array('EventsMember.is_confirmed'=>0)
    )
);
```

.. works absolutely fine in SQLite, but not in MySQL. What happens in MySQL? This:

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Event.course_id' in 'where clause'

(More details on that error here: http://pastebin.com/5byPu9NR)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) because as the manual says:

> In CakePHP some associations (belongsTo and hasOne) perform automatic joins to retrieve data [...] but this is not the case with hasMany and hasAndBelongsToMany associations.

Comment: Thanks - but: 

-Why would that be necessary with MySQl but not be necessary with SQLite? and
-I need to be doing this in the Model, not the Controller - remember, Fat Models, Thin Controllers.

Comment: You can put the joins in your controller or model, model is indeed preferred. Are you sure that the exact same code works with one DB and not other AND produces expected results? This restriction is cake, not DB based, so my guess is that either SQLite is doing some guessing adding what is missing or it fails silently and produces unexpected results. I don't have any expertise on SQLite so I don't know what is going on. But you can take the SQL that is generated from cake (should be the same in both DBs), run it manually and see what it does in each case.